# Reading value from remote website using WebClient

Tags: c#, .net

```
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();

    // Add a user agent header in case the 
    // requested URI contains a query.

    client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");

    Stream data = client.OpenRead("http://www.nseindia.com/marketinfo/indices/indexwatch.jsp");
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
    string s = null;
    int count = 0;
    while (reader.Read()>0)
    {
        s = reader.ReadLine();
        if (s.Contains("<td class=t1>"))
        {
           s= s.Remove(0, 18);
           s = s.Remove(s.Length - 5);
           count++;
           if (count == 5)
               break;
        }

    }


   // MessageBox.Show(s);
    data.Close();
    reader.Close();
    return s;
}
```

Will you plz help me to run this ....

Comment: Are you getting a specific error? What exactly is not working?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I am downloading a link from nseindia site using my program but now I cant do it there is a error 403?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906811/i-am-downloading-a-link-from-nseindia-site-using-my-program-but-now-i-cant-do-it)

Comment: in case you missed the answer in your duplicate question, you need to add this line to your code: `client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";` I've done that now and it really solved the 403 error.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `reader.Read()` which consumes a character and *then* you're reading a line. I suggest you change your loop to:

```
string line;

while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    ...
}
```

You should also use `using` statements so that everything will be closed even if an exception is thrown. Oh, and I'd use `string.Substring` instead of `string.Remove`.

I'd probably also use `client.DownloadString` to get the whole lot in one go instead of opening a stream. It's just simpler.

Comment: quick test of the code showed the real problem.. luckily it was already asked and solved. :-)

Comment: @Shadow: When you say "the real problem" - he would still have been reading broken data... but thanks for finding the duplicate.